# Is it a good practice to validate a form based on element's color?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm working on a form which has a validation script before submitting data.

Basically in all input fields, I have a function to test if the content of input is correct, triggered by 'onchange' event. If the content is 'invalid', the function will set the background of that input field to red.

```
function looseColorQty(t)
    {
     var n = t.value;
     if(isNaN(n) == true || n < 0){
         t.style.backgroundColor="red";    
    } else {
        t.style.backgroundColor="";
        } 
     }
```

Then when the user click 'submit' button, there's another script to check if this form can be submitted based on if any of the input fields is 'red'.

```
var canNotSubmit = 0;
function checkError(){
    var fieldsToCheck = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var fieldsQty = fieldsToCheck.length;

    for(var i=0; i<fieldsQty; i++){
        var checkTarget = fieldsToCheck[i].style.backgroundColor;

            if( checkTarget == "red"){
            document.getElementById("tips").className = "tipError";
            document.getElementById("tips").innerHTML = "Please correct all RED fields before you submit.";
            canNotSubmit = 1;
            return;
        }
        }
        }
```

It actually works but I just have a weird feeling that this validation is based on color. I wanna know if there's any drawback by doting so.

Comment: It's not a best practice because the color red could mean anything. It would be better to have `checkError()` do two things: 1. it should color the element red, 2. In the loop it should keep track of `numErrors` (a new variable that counts up every time an error is found). Then you should use `numErrors` to determine whether or not the form is valid. It's a subtle difference, but will make maintaining the application easier, later

Comment: As long as there is server side validation that is fine I believe. Just want to make sure you don't get any false negatives and users cannot use the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not a good idea.

Instead, if you're not using HTML5 field validation, I would attach (or change) an attribute on the field; for instance instead of setting `t.style.backgroundColor="red"` attach a `data-validation="invalid"` attribute, and then use your CSS to *style* it as a red background.

Base things on semantics (meaning) not on appearance.

Then you onsubmit handler can check for any `data-validation="invalid"` fields and issue messages based on those.

Don't forget to **always** validate *again* on the server after the submit, because you can't trust the client-side validation -- the data can always be tampered with after it has passed client validation.

Comment: +1 for using server-side validation as primary validation method.  Any validation you put in client-side is ONLY a convenience to the user.  Never trust data 'validated' by the client.

Comment: @ChrisWillard - and +1 for "a convenience to the user", that is the exact phrase I use all the time.

Comment: Thank you Stephen P. By adding an attribute, it makes me much easier to manipulate the validation. And for sure I'll write the validation on the server side too.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an additional classname to the element. Like `value-is-invalid`. Than you could check if the elements classname contains this class. You can also move your `background-color: red;` into this class in a css file. So you can seperate style from logic and change the style more easier later.

Like:

```
.value-is-invalid {
    background-color: red;
}
```

As Stephen P pointed out you can't rely on client-side validation. always validate on server-side, too.